# ERRO - DJANGO 2.0.9 - TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'

Tags: django, django-2.0

Conseguem me ajudar com o seguinte problema, sou novato no Django:

Então, estou fazendo um curso na internet para criação de uma plataforma de ensino a distância para aprender sobre Django. Estou utilizando a versão Django 2.0.9, estou com problema durante a criação do super usuário, o curso que estou seguindo utilizando uma versão do django mais antiga que no momento de criação do banco de dados socilitava o cadastramento do Administrador logo após. Comando antigo:

```
$ python manage syncdb
```

Porém esse comando não existe mais (pelo que entendi), então estou utilizando a sequencia de comandos abaixo:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Eu criei um usuário customizado e defini como usuário padrão do Django incluindo a informação `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'` na **settings.py**, porém o campo **email não aparece durante a criação do super usuário e ocorre o erro abaixo:**

```
Nome de Usuário: gabriel
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Curso/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 179, in handle self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
**TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'**
```

Tentei comentar o campo `REQUERID_FIELDS = ['email']` na classe do Usuário Custom, deletei o banco de dados e migrei os dados novamente, porém não funcionou, ele continua acusando a ausência do campo **email**.

Segue model do Usuário Custom definido como padrão:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, 
                                    UserManager)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField('Nome de Usuário', max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Está ativo?', blank=True, default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('É da equipe?', blank=True, default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateField('Data de Cadastro', auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUERID_FIELDS = ['email']

    # Define a representação string do objeto
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name or self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return str(self)

    class Meta:  
        verbose_name = 'Usuário'  
        verbose_name_plural = 'Usuários'
```

Comment: Consegui resolver ! hahahahahah, porém não consigo explicar foram tantos comandos efetuados no terminal.

Comment: De qualquer forma vc tem que fazer o que aponto na minha resposta, se não vc tera problemas no futuro, caindo em uma especie de armadilha. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na definição da classe User, onde vc informa USER_NAME_FIELD, acrescente o EMAIL_FIELD, assim:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField('Nome de Usuário', max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Está ativo?', blank=True, default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('É da equipe?', blank=True, default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateField('Data de Cadastro', auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'  # ====> Acrescente essa linha
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUERID_FIELDS = ['email']
    ....
```